# stm32cubeide reports firmware package is missing

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, nucleo, stm32cubeide

I have a STM32 Nucleo F4 and I am trying to create a new C project in STMCubeIDE.

I have STMCubeIDE version 1.5.0 Build: 8698_20201117_1050 (UTC)

In the Embedded Software Packages Manager I have installed "STM32Cube MCU Package for STM32F4 Series" version 1.25.2

However, when I go to create a new STM32 project (using the board selector to select my board - NUCLEO-F410RB) I get the following error message:

`Code generation could not be done most probably because the necessary firmware package is missing. Not able to complete STM32Cube project creation. See Firmware Updater for settings related to firmware package installation Tips: Please use the Device Configuration Tool, and then use 'Project > Generate Code' to complete the project generation.`

If I call 'Project > Generate Code' it seems to complete, but most of the project files are missing, which means 'generate code' has failed silently at some stage.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After more searching I finally found this:
https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BeZi12/code-generation-could-not-be-done-firmware-package-v1241-can-not-be-unzipped

The solution from there worked for me:

1. From this page https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef4.html download two zips (STM32CubeF4 and Patch-CubeF4)
2. Unpack first en.STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.24.0.zip to Repository folder
3. Then unpack en.patch_cubefw_f4.zip to the same folder with file replacement
4. Done!

I downloaded V1.25.0 and the patch.
The repository folder was under C:/Users//STM32CUBE/Repository

Comment: Hello, I tried to follow these steps. Unpacked "en.stm32cubef4_v1-26-0_v1.26.0" and "en.patch_cubef4_v1-26-2_v1.26.2". But it did not work. What does it mean unpack with file replacement? I unpacked both of them in "Repository" folder. They did not replace anything. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Surprisingly, After following the above steps, I tried to open a new project and then it works. But I have no idea why the existing old one did not work after the above steps. Thanks @DavidW

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **IDE** working, choose menu item `Help`**->**"`Manage Embedded Software Packages`"

It will guide you to install the FW package you noted above.  Afterwards, you can import the examples from that zip file into your **IDE** as a project.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and I managed to solve it with the following steps:

- changed the firmware storage location for the board. For instance, I moved it from the `C` drive to the `D` drive;
- after changing the location, start creating a new project again;
- the necessary zip file will be downloaded again.

These are the steps which helped me to resolve the issue for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35566699)